# ibmcloud cr login inside pipeline

Tags: ibm-cloud, tekton

Want to login to container registry (so I can use buildah to deploy on IBM Cloud), using the following task (others removed for simplicity):

```
- name: login1
  taskRef:
    name: ibmcloud
  params:
  - name: ARGS
    value: 
      - "login"
      - "--apikey=$(params.ibmcloud-api-key)"
      - "-g"
      - "production"
      - "-r"
      - "$(params.ibmcloud-region)"

- name: cr-login
  taskRef:
    name: ibmcloud
  params:
  - name: ARGS
    value: 
      - "cr"
      - "login"
  runAfter:
    - login1
```

The error I receive is:

```
[login1 : ibmcloud] API endpoint: https://cloud.ibm.com
[login1 : ibmcloud] Authenticating...
[login1 : ibmcloud] OK
...
[cr-login : ibmcloud] 
[cr-login : ibmcloud] Warning: an error occurred while checking updates for plug-in 'container-registry':
[cr-login : ibmcloud] Could not get plugins from repository: invalid character '<' looking for beginning of value
[cr-login : ibmcloud] Use 'ibmcloud config --check-version=false' to disable update check.
[cr-login : ibmcloud] 
[cr-login : ibmcloud] FAILED
[cr-login : ibmcloud] You are not logged in to IBM Cloud.
[cr-login : ibmcloud] Log in by running the 'ibmcloud login' command.
```

Comment: are you sure the error is associated with the task provided above?

Answer (score 0):

This indicates the IBM Cloud CLI version is likely older than 2.0. You'll need to upgrade the CLI. To move up to 2.x it requires a manual install, not just an update. You can find instructions for installing at https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/cli?topic=cli-install-ibmcloud-cli . And there's more details about the problem you're hitting at https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/cli?topic=cli-troubleshoot#ts-cli-version-1-failure